# Duplicated the player scene but only the running animation is not playing

Tags: animation, movement, gdscript

First time asking a question here, so hopefully it goes well! So, I had a player scene set up with a custom state machine, for now handling the idle, run and jump stages, currently set up as nodes:

[image: CharacterStateMachine Inspector]

This player1 plays all animations correctly, however, since I was following a tutorial and wanted to change how my movement logic worked, I duplicated the player1 scene and tried to merge the two scripts (State Machine and animation logic from player1 with movement logic to player2).

All animations play correctly, idle when idle, jumping when jumping, landing when landing, but when running the sprite just stays static.

I've gone back and forth from player1 scene to player2 scene to make sure I've selected the correct nodes, but I can't figure out why all animations play except the running animation. Below is the full Player2 script, I'm activating the animation tree in the _ready function, I'm setting the parameters of Move which is a blendSpace1D with the idle and running animations and I'm calling it in the _physics_proccess.

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var movement_data: PlayerMovementData

var air_jump = false
var just_wall_jumped = false
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var was_wall_normal = Vector2.ZERO
var direction : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO

@onready var sprite_2d = $Sprite2D
@onready var animated_sprite_2d = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var coyote_jump_timer = $CoyoteTimer
@onready var wall_jump_timer = $WallJumpTimer
@onready var animation_tree : AnimationTree = $AnimationTree
@onready var state_machine : CharacterStateMachine = $CharacterStateMachine

func _ready():
    animation_tree.active = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    apply_gravity(delta)
    update_animation_parameters()
    handle_wall_jump()
    handle_jump()
    var input_axis = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
    handle_acceleration(input_axis, delta)
    handle_air_acceleration(input_axis, delta)
    apply_friction(input_axis, delta)
    apply_air_resistance(input_axis, delta)
    var was_on_floor = is_on_floor()
    var was_on_wall = is_on_wall_only()
    if was_on_wall:
        was_wall_normal = get_wall_normal()
    move_and_slide()
    var just_left_ledge = was_on_floor and not is_on_floor() and velocity.y >= 0
    if just_left_ledge:
        coyote_jump_timer.start()
    just_wall_jumped = false
    var just_left_wall = was_on_wall and not is_on_wall()
    if just_left_wall:
        wall_jump_timer.start()
    
    update_animations(input_axis)
    

func apply_gravity(delta):
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * movement_data.gravity_scale * delta

func handle_wall_jump():
    if not is_on_wall_only() and wall_jump_timer.time_left <= 0.0: return
    var wall_normal = get_wall_normal() 
    if wall_jump_timer.time_left > 0.0:
        wall_normal = was_wall_normal
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        velocity.x = wall_normal.x * movement_data.speed
        velocity.y = movement_data.jump_velocity
        just_wall_jumped = true

func handle_jump():
    if is_on_floor(): air_jump = true
    
    if is_on_floor() or coyote_jump_timer.time_left > 0.0:
        if Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
            velocity.y = movement_data.jump_velocity
            coyote_jump_timer.stop()
    elif not is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_just_released("jump") and velocity.y < movement_data.jump_velocity / 2:
            velocity.y = movement_data.jump_velocity / 2
        
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and air_jump and not just_wall_jumped:
            velocity.y = movement_data.jump_velocity * 0.8
            air_jump = false

func handle_acceleration(input_axis, delta):
    if not is_on_floor(): return
    if input_axis != 0 && state_machine.checkIfCanMove():
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, movement_data.speed * input_axis, movement_data.acceleration * delta)

func handle_air_acceleration(input_axis, delta):
    if is_on_floor(): return
    if input_axis != 0 && state_machine.checkIfCanMove():
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, movement_data.speed * input_axis, movement_data.air_acceleration * delta)

func apply_friction(input_axis, delta):
    if input_axis == 0 and is_on_floor():
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, movement_data.friction * delta)

func apply_air_resistance(input_axis, delta):
    if input_axis == 0 and not is_on_floor():
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, movement_data.air_resistance * delta)

func update_animation_parameters():
    animation_tree.set("parameters/Move/blend_position", direction.x)

func update_animations(input_axis):
    if input_axis > 0:
        sprite_2d.flip_h = false
        sprite_2d.offset.x = -15
    elif input_axis < 0:
        sprite_2d.flip_h = true
        sprite_2d.offset.x = -75
```

I'm sorry if it's a bit confusing, I'll try to clarify any raised questions and I appreciate any help with this, I'm sure it's something dumb but after a full afternoon of trying to resolve this, I need help. So once again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Do the properties for the AnimationPlayer in the inspector match? Do the animations show correctly in the Animation panel? Do you get any error or warning when running the animations?